# Azure App Service build fails due to error MSB3191: Unable to create directory

Tags: azure, razor, msbuild, azure-web-app-service, .net-5

**Platform:**  Azure App Service

**Deployment:**  Local Git

**Version:**  .NET 5

When deploying updates (git push to remote Local Git in Azure) .NET 5 Razor Pages app to Azure App Service, the KUDU build fails with the error below.  I can solve the problem by using the Console in the Azure Portal to manually delete the entire /obj directory, then the build succeeds.  But ideally this would not be necessary every time I need to push an update.  Is there a simple way to prevent this error?

### Error in terminal after  "git push" to remote:

```
remote: RazorCoreGenerate:
remote:   Removing directory "obj\Release\net5.0\Razor\".
remote:   Creating directory "obj\Release\net5.0\Razor\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\".
remote: D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets(146,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "obj\Release\net5.0\Razor\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\". Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Release\net5.0\Razor\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\'. [D:\home\site\repository\abc.csproj]
remote: Done Building Project "D:\home\site\repository\abc.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
remote:
remote: Build FAILED.
remote:
remote: "D:\home\site\repository\abc.csproj" (default target) (1:7) ->
remote: (RazorCoreGenerate target) ->
remote:   D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets(146,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "obj\Release\net5.0\Razor\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\". Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Release\net5.0\Razor\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\'. [D:\home\site\repository\abc.csproj]
remote:
remote:     0 Warning(s)
remote:     1 Error(s)
remote:
remote: Time Elapsed 00:01:54.09
remote: Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuilds\16.8.3\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /restore "D:\home\site\repository\abc.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:configuration=Release /p:publishurl="D:\local\Temp\8d9118005db4f8f"
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

*(My apologies in advance.  This is my first question ever posted on stackoverflow)*

Answer (score 0):

*1. Check the folder permission.*

*2. Open `cmd` tool as `Administrator`, then `re-run` your command.*

If you use command in visual studio tools, you also need to run Visual Studio as an administrator.